# Storing ClosedRange<Float> via @AppStorage

Tags: swift, appstorage, rawrepresentable

Following [this tutorial](https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/SaveCustomCodableTypesInAppStorageOrSceneStorage/) I would like to store `ClosedRange<Float>` using `@AppStorage`. I've extended `ClosedRange` as follows:

```swift
extension ClosedRange where Bound == Float {
    init?(rawValue: String) {
        let components = rawValue.split(separator: ",").compactMap { Float($0) }
        guard components.count == 2 else { return nil }
        self = components[0]...components[1]
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        return "\(lowerBound),\(upperBound)"
    }
}
```

In my view I would like to use `@AppStorage` in the following manner:

```swift
@AppStorage("range_slider_position", store: .group) var sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float> = 20...80
```

Presently the code returns the error:

```
<view_definition_file...>.swift:16:3 No exact matches in call to initializer 

Candidate requires that the types 'ClosedRange<Float>' and 'Bool' be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == 'Bool') (SwiftUI.AppStorage)
Candidate requires that the types 'ClosedRange<Float>' and 'Int' be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == 'Int') (SwiftUI.AppStorage)
Candidate requires that the types 'ClosedRange<Float>' and 'Double' be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == 'Double') (SwiftUI.AppStorage)
Candidate requires that the types 'ClosedRange<Float>' and 'String' be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == 'String') (SwiftUI.AppStorage)
Candidate requires that the types 'ClosedRange<Float>' and 'URL' be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == 'URL') (SwiftUI.AppStorage)
Candidate requires that the types 'ClosedRange<Float>' and 'Data' be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == 'Data') (SwiftUI.AppStorage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one of your tags, the extension must adopt `RawRepresentable`.
And the protocol methods must be declared `public`

```
extension ClosedRange : RawRepresentable where Bound == Float {
   public init?(rawValue: String) {
        let components = rawValue.split(separator: ",").compactMap { Float($0) }
        guard components.count == 2 else { return nil }
        self = components[0]...components[1]
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        return "\(lowerBound),\(upperBound)"
    }
}
```